# Why two requests when I download a file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I have an action which serves a file:

```
public override FileContentResult Foo() {
  var someDataAsBytes = ...
  return File(someDataAsBytes, "text/csv", "somefilename.csv");
}
```

The form is simple:

```
<form method="get" action="/Foo" id="myForm">
  <button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

I initiate the download via script (so the page doesn't change):

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).attr("action");
  return false;
});
```

Problem is that two requests are sent to the server: one GET and one HEAD. And the action runs twice, but only serves the file once.

*How do I get it to only send one request? Or is this normal behavior?*

Extra info:
I inspected this in Fiddler, and the responses to the GET and POST are identical, except the GET has a non-zero `Content-Length` and the actual payload data. The response to the HEAD has nothing. Both return 200 OK status codes. Is this normal?

Comment: Can you post the html? specifically the `form` tag.

Comment: @ramiramilu added markup

Comment: @hbob: why are you redirecting after submitting form. remove this line 
`window.location.href = $(this).attr("action");`  this line will call GET method not the post.

Comment: I replicated your code in my local, and I was not able to get second time hit. There may be other parts of the code which is causing the problem.

Comment: @AmitKumar That line is to ensure the page does not change. It asks "do you want to open/save" but the page remains as is. It is standard practice as far as I can tell.

Comment: Try adding event.preventDefault.

Comment: @ramiramilu Thanks for doing that! That confirms the second request is NOT normal. PS, which browser did you test in?

Comment: chrome Version 43.0.2357.81

Comment: @ramiramilu AHA! I just tested in more browsers, and I only get this problem in Firefox! I wonder what it could be. I guess it's either standard for Firefox, or due to some plugin.

Comment: in fact in Firefox, I tried and i am not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @ramiramilu Post something as an answer, so I can accept it! :-)

Comment: @ramiramilu So then it must be a Firefox plugin I'm using. In which case, I can probably safely ignore this problem, even though I can't find the cause.

Comment: Can you disable all the plugins in FF and give a try and let me know, then I can post the solution as answer :-)

Comment: @ramiramilu Good idea, now I just need to find out how to do that... give me a bit of time... OK turns out it's easy, just "Help" then "Restart with Addons disabled"

Comment: @ramiramilu YES that worked! So it's definitely some naughty plugin. Please add your anwer, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong with your code. I replicated your code and tried to reproduce the issue which you are facing. But I am not able to repro in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

It looks like this issue is specific to FireFox browser of yours and due to some plugin/Extension. Disable all the plugins in the browser and give it a try, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing with `e.preventDefault()` in your script. What is happening here is your action is hit by both script and normal post. So if you put `e.preventDefault()` like below, then it will prevent browser's default postback and only javascript's code will execute your request.

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = $(this).attr("action");
});
```

Comment: Not true. In a jQuery handler, `return false` means 1) `preventDefault()`, 2) `stopPropagation()` and 3) returns false immediately. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).